# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `RNCSafeAreaProvider` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, dependencies

Recently, I went to update my React Native app's dependencies by running `npm update`. This was a big mistake and broke everything :) so I checked out the previous `package-lock.json`, deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm i` again.

Far as I know, this should've put everything back to how it was, but instead I'm getting this error (among many others):

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `RNCSafeAreaProvider` must be a function (received `undefined`).

This error is located at:
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider <- Imported from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
    in MyApp <- My code
```

I understand this error usually happens when you try to render an invalid component, ie. because you imported from the wrong place.

However, and **this is what makes my question not a duplicate of those asking about similar errors**, this isn't coming from my code. You can see from the call stack that it successfully resolves and starts to render `SafeAreaProvider`, which is *not* my component, it's straight from `react-native-safe-area-context`. Then, within there it tries to render a component that's internal to that package, `RNCSafeAreaProvider` and fails.

I'm confident that the code for this view isn't wrong - it was working before I went messing with `npm`. The issue is also reproducible across iOS & Android.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up tracking this down to a mistake. The project is organised with npm workspaces, and I had done `npm i` from within one of the sub-projects instead of just from the root of the project.

Not sure why it caused such a cryptic error but hopefully this can help someone else diagnose the same issue

Comment: This didn't work for me. I was using React Native Elements in the React JS Web as well React Native with yarn workspaces. I had to remove react-native-safe-area-context from my Web's package.json. This is a very strange behaviour. I am probably going to try nohoist and check.

Comment: @GauthamPai I am also facing the same issue. Did you try nohoist? May I know what nohoist config you used?

Comment: I suspect this whole issue was because react-native did not used to support symlinks which the npm workspace does use.